# Help with asp login SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql, authentication, get

I have a form which goes to the following login script when it is submitted.

```
<%
    Dim myConnection As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim myCommand As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim requestName As String
    Dim requestPass As String
    requestName = Request.Form("userName")
    requestPass = Request.Form("userPass")
    Dim queryString As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Num_Of_User FROM tblusers WHERE username='" & requestName & "' AND password='" & requestPass & "'"
    myConnection = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);InitialCatalog=dbtest;Integrated Security=True")
    myCommand = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(queryString, myConnection)
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim reader As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
%>
```

Now in theory, I should be able to get that Num_Of_User from the SQL Query and if it equals 1 than the login was successful. Is this the correct way? And how can I get the value that the SQL returns?

Comment: You appear to be using ASP.NET, not ASP. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, they are all .aspx pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `myCommand.ExecuteScalar()`, which returns the value from the first column in the first row of the resultset - exactly the value you're after here.

Also, check into the ASP.Net 'built in' authentication methods - this might save you some effort.

Comment: So could this be correct to get the value:

Dim rows
rows = myCommand.ExecuteScalar()

Comment: `Dim UserCount As Integer = DirectCast(myCommand.ExecuteScalar(), Integer)` would the the way to use this.

Answer (score 4):

**You are wide open to SQL injection using that code.**

See happens if you enter the username as `' OR 2>1--`

You need to change the to use a parametrized query.

```
Dim queryString As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Num_Of_User FROM tblusers WHERE username=@username AND password=@password"
myConnection = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);InitialCatalog=dbtest;Integrated Security=True")
myCommand = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(queryString, myConnection)
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", requestName)
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", requestPass)
```

**Also you are not handling any exceptions that might be thrown, nor disposing your objects.**

Your code should look more like the following.

```
Dim numUsers as Integer
Using myConnection as New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);InitialCatalog=dbtest;Integrated Security=True")
   Dim queryString As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Num_Of_User FROM tblusers WHERE username=@username AND password=@password"
   Using myCommand as New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(queryString, myConnection)
      myConnection.Open
      myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", requestName)
      myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", requestPass) 
      numUsers = myCommand.ExecuteScalar()
   End Using
End Using
```

The above code will make sure your objects are disposed, but won't handle any exceptions that might be thrown.

Comment: I'm getting an error on the the first Using line. It says: "BC3016: Variable 'myConnection hides a variable in an enclosing block.'"

Comment: You don't need a `Dim myConnection as SqlConnection` statement. The `Using` statement declares the variable, and disposes it when out of scope - i.e after `End Using`.